# If $\frac{d}{dt} f(x,t)>\frac{1}{t^{\alpha}}$ for $0< \alpha\le1$, then $f(x,t)$ is not uniformly bounded.

Tags: analysis

I am trying to a function $f(x,t)$ is not uniformly bounded if $\frac{d}{dt}f(x,t)>\frac{1}{t^{\alpha}}$ for $0< \alpha\le1$.

By definition, I started by assuming that there is a number $C$, which is independent to $t$, such that $|f(x,t)|\le C$ to get contradiction. However, there is no idea to prove it.

Comment: $f(x,t)-f(x,0)=\int_0^{t} \frac {\partial} {\partial s} f(x,s) ds$.

Comment: That implies right hand side has a lower bound as  $(1-\alpha)^{-1} t^{1-\alpha}$.  Oh, than I may get some large $C_t$ which satisfies $C_t>C$ since $(1-\alpha)^{-1} t^{1-\alpha}$ approaches to $\infty$ when $0<\alpha\le 1$.